# How to receive Push notification from sup(2.1.3)

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, apple-push-notifications, sup

As per the sybase documentation in the following link

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01205.0211/doc/html/aba1258735405889.html

1. have uploaded  the .p12 development certificate in SCC
2. Then push enabled RFC and MBO are ready with us

Since we are new to this APNS, we are not sure how to receive those notifications sent by the SUP server

Please guide us to do the same..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUP server sends push notifications to the device when there is a data change at the cache database, Upon receiving the push notification it perform auto synchronization, So You can override this auto synchronization in case you dont want this sync to happen or something else by registering a callback handler.

Comment: do u have any tutorials or sample codes regarding this..
thanks in advance